# Is it possible to modify the highlighted color and font size of SBTableAlert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm using the SBTableAlert (see here: https://github.com/mindbrix/SBTableAlert) and wanted to know if it's possible to change the highlighted color. It's currently blue, but I would prefer another. I would also prefer to have the option text a bit smaller and not bold, but I don't see where this is set.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside SBTableAlert.m find the following:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
```

In there you can just include this and your background color will be changed:

```
//Example with a predefined color
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

or

```
//Example with an RGB color
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:155.0f/255.0f green:155.0f/255.0f blue:155.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
[self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this lines to your RootViewController.m in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if ([indexPath row] == 1)
    {
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"Single Select"];
       cell.textLabel.font = [cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:10];
    }
    else if ([indexPath row] == 0){
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"Multiple Select"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:10];}
    else if ([indexPath row] == 2){
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"Apple Style"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:10];}
    else if ([indexPath row] == 3){
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"Sections"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:10];}

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This will change main tableview, not alertview table.